# GIT Push does nothing after executing git config command in Linux

Tags: git, github

I had issues while pushing my code to my repo, and the git had given an warning to use either,

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

OR

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

where I had used the first command => `git config --global push.default matching`

After executing the above command, when I try to execute `git push` it does nothing, and the command is not getting executed at all.

P.S: I'm working on a Linux box.

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Are your remote tracking branches set correctly?

Comment: Just beware that `matching` as a value for `push.default` will make the `git push` command (without other parameters) try to push *every* existing local branch to its remote counterpart. It might be what you want or not, just to mention it.

Comment: @Dai Yes, It is there.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks for the heads-up. Since I've executed it, is there any way to rollback it, (in other words), what is the default config setting, How do I set it through command?

Comment: The second line you quoted (with `simple`) would restore the default ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault)). As a sidenote, if you happen to use a version older than 2.0, then `matching` *would* be the default, but I guess it's unlikely?

Comment: @RomainValeri That did the trick!.. Thanks for reply. Can you please post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidR Glad that it worked, but my side answer is not really answering the title question...